# Automate multiple Excel files into one Tableau visualization

Tags: excel, refresh, datasource, tableau-api

I have an Excel file with daily stats posted on a shared network folder each day. The structure of the table is exactly the same but a new file is posted each day as opposed to appending the new day's data to a single file.

I want to automate pulling data from each of these daily files when they are posted into Tableau and depict it in a time series to show how the stats are changing each day. Is this possible? if yes, how?

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Look into the Union feature in Tableau.

Comment: Could you create a separate 'master' Excel file with some form of macro that would append data from any newly created file?  Then you can connect that to Tableau